# Get ARAccountRef is invalid when adding second invoice for the same customer

Tags: intuit-partner-platform, qbxml

I have invoices that add ok but will not sync.  Below is the error I get back from `SyncStatusRequest`.  Research suggests this error is related to payments but I am adding invoices.  And stranger still, I only seem to have this problem when I add two invoices in a row for the same customer (1st is fine, 2nd will not sync).  Anyone have any ideas?

**QBXML validation error:**

```
[severity=FATAL_ERROR,message=cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: 
   Invalid content was found starting with element 'ARAccountRef'. One of   '{CustomerRef}' is expected.,
   locator=url=null,
   line=-1,
   column=-1,
   node=null,
   object=com.intuit.sb.datasync.writeback.qbxml.schema.ARAccountRef@392ac48b,
   field=null]
```

]

Comment: Can you post each of the two XML requests you're sending to Intuit?

Comment: Done.  Also in testing further it is related to adding a customer then adding more than one invoice.